# Generate AST using ANTLR4 generated visitor

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am converting an ANTLR3 grammar to an ANTLR4 grammar, this means that I had to remove all tree rewriting rules because they now have to be implemented in code and by visiting `ParseTree` with a custom `Visitor` it's possible to generate an AST.

The old grammar had rewrite rules that prevented ambiguities and automatically generated the wanted tree. I couldn't find any useful resource online showing how this can be done with the visitor/listener paradigm.

1. A `Visitor` needs a type that is used as return type for all the `visit*` functions. If I need to generate an AST, what return type should I use? ANTLR3 used `CommonTree` objects.
2. When entering a `visit*` node, I can create a node of the tree, but how should I track its parent node?
3. Is there any example on how to convert a tree rewrite rule to a method generating a node of the AST? If not, would it be possible to have an example for a rule like the one below?

Here the rule for (3):

```
ctor_initializer: '::'? identifier '(' expr? ')' -> ^(CTOR_INITIALIZER^(INITIALIZER_ID '::'? identifier) ^(CTOR_EXPR expr?) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, Antlr4 creates and supports use of parse-trees.  There is no direct support for creating and modifying ASTs.

Some of the motivating factors for preferring parse-trees over ASTs are [summarized here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312976/antlr-4-parser-grammar/30335862#30335862).

Antlr4 does not preclude constructing ASTs -- the structure can be defined in any manner desired. Some examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971097/how-to-create-ast-with-antlr4?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843831/antlr4-parse-tree-simplification?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for the links, however `(3)` is not covered in the other questions because they all assume to create a new grammar instead of converting antlr3 grammar rules.

Comment: Yes.  The lack of examples anywhere on the 'net along the lines of (3) gives a telling indication of how frequently that path is taken.